# Typescript get function parameters

Tags: node.js, typescript

```
let func = (myFunc: (arg1: any, arg2: any) => void)=>{
    // WHEN I PASS the *testFunction* in parameter: 

    console.log(myFunc.name);// THIS PRINTS "testFunction"

    //console.log( typeof myFunc.params[1])   /* I WANT THIS TO LOG "string" */

    //console.log( typeof myFunc.params[2])   /* I WANT THIS TO LOG "number" */

}

let testFunction = (arg1: string, arg2: number) => { }
```

I need to know the type of arguments of the function that has been passed.

Anyone can help please?

Comment: The expected type is `any`.

Comment: Please provide reproducible example without syntax errors

Comment: Is this a TypeScript question or a JavaScript question? Are you trying to find out the expected parameter at compile time or at runtime? Do you mean `myFunc: (arg1: string, arg2: number)`?

Comment: @jabaa I want it at runtime

Comment: There is no TypeScript at runtime. In that case it's a JavaScript question, unrelated to TypeScript. TypeScript code is transpiled to JavaScript code at compile time/transpile time.

Comment: @jabaa I mean any other function could have been passed instead of testFunction . Like **anotherTestFunction: (arg1: boolean, arg2: never)** . And I want to log the types of the passed function arguments.

Comment: You can't read TypeScript types at runtime. They don't exist. Where does `myFunc.params` come from?

Comment: @jabaa I get that. So is there a way to read that at compile time?

Comment: No, because you can call `func` at runtime with different arguments. It's impossible withtout time travel.

Comment: @jabaa I think  I got it now!

Comment: [Parameters<Type>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype)

Comment: @Nick How exactly would this help getting the types of `testFunction` through `myFunc`? `myFunc` has `myFunc: (arg1: any, arg2: any) => void`

Comment: That's a typescript type, it would not work at runtime, i commented it just to add a reference for future cases